# Eclipse conditional breakpoint compilation error "==" invalid AssignmentOperator

Tags: eclipse, conditional-breakpoint

So if I got it right, you're supposed to use a boolean expression for the condition. Yet when I try to use `impact == null` I get the following error:

```
Conditional breakpoint has compilation error(s).

Reason:
Syntax error on token "==", invalid AssignmentOperator.
```

What gives? What did I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: @ryekayo He is using a breakpoint with a special condition.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Which language?

Comment: @nitind Java (latest version) and the eclipse release 4.3.2.

Answer (score 13):

Just a wild guess as I faced a similar problem some moments ago:
 You have written `impact == null;` instead of `impact == null`.

If this is the case: try removing the semicolon.

Comment: This was the problem for me too, in Eclipse 4.4.0. Seems like a bug or design misfeature on their part because to me, as a user, there is no obvious reason why it should interpret the condition differently with the semicolon vs. without.